# Mongoose - REST API - Schema With Query to different model

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I'm trying to avoid DB Callback Queries.

Assuming that you have two schemas that looks like so :

> 1st) ***User Schema***

```
 username : {type: String, unique: true},
 age : {type: Number}
```

> 2nd) ***Activity Schema***

```
 owner: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
 city: {type: String},
 date: {type: Date}
```

So far so good.

Now lets say you have a route to `/user/:id`, what you would expect is to get the `username` and the `age`, but what if I would also like to return on that route the **latest activity**?

**EDIT: Please note that `latest activity` isn't a value in the database. it's calculated automatically like `activity.find({owner: ObjectId(id)}).sort({date: -1}).limit(1)`**

What is done right now:

```
User.findOne({username:req.params.username}).lean().exec(function(err,userDoc)
{

   if(err) return errHandler(err);

   Activity.findOne({owner:userDoc.username}).sort({date:-1}).exec(function(err,EventDoc){

     if(err) return errHandler(err);

     userDoc.latest_activity = EventDoc._id;

     res.json(userDoc);
     res.end();

   })

})
```

**The problem with the snippet above is that it is hard to maintain, 
What if we want to add more to this API functionality? We would end in a callback of hell of queries unless we implement Q.**

> We tried to look at Virtual but the issue with that is that you can't
>   really query inside a mongoose Virtual, since it returns a
>   race-condition, and you are most likely not get that document on time.

**We also tried to look at populate, but we couldn't make it since the documentation on populate is super poor.**

**QUESTION:**
**Is there anyway making this more modular?**

**Is there any way avoiding the DB Query Callback of Hell?**

For example is this sort of thing possible?

```
    User.findOne({username:req.params.username}).lean().populate(
{path:'Event',sort:{Date:-1}, limit(1)}
).exec(function(req,res))...
```

Thanks!

Comment: I updated it again, it should be way clearer. I think its absurd that no one tackled this.

Comment: You're doing a manual join.  There look to be a number of modules in the space: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mongo+join   (or if you really have relational data, use a relational database)

Comment: So what you are saying here is that if I'm trying to build a REST API route that returns extra data ( with queries to different collections ) beside the document, there is no way of avoiding Callback Hell Queries unless I use RDBMS, right? There must be another way.. Schema Design to Features in mongoose

Comment: `populate` only works from the model that contains the ref (`Activity` in this case).  So you can get the latest activity for the user and populate its `owner` array, but not the other way around.

Comment: You can avoid callback hell in a number of ways, the async module, promises etc . . . but if you're spending your time manually joining collections, something is wrong.  Another option is laying out your data such that you don't need to join it, such as when an activity occurs update the user with a last_activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by @BrianShambien's answer you could go with the post save, but instead of just storing the `_id` on the user you store a sub doc of only the last activity. Then when you grab that user it has the last activity right there.

User Model

```
username :     {type: String, unique: true},
age :          {type: Number},
last_activity: ActivitySchema
```

Then you do a post save hook on your `ActivitySchema`

```
ActivitySchema.post('save', function(doc) {
    UserSchema.findOne({username: doc.owner}).exec(function(err, user){
        if (err) errHandler(err);

        user.last_activity = doc;

        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) errHandler(err);
        });
    });
});
```

**********UPDATE************

This is to include the update to the user if they are not an owner, but a particpant of the the activity.

```
ActivitySchema.post('save', function(doc) {
    findAndUpdateUser(doc.owner, doc);

    if (doc.participants) {
        for (var i in doc.participants) {
            findAndUpdateUser(doc.participants[i], doc);
        }
    }
});

var findAndUpdateUser = function (username, doc) {
    UserSchema.findOne({username: username}).exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) errHandler(err);

        user.last_activity = doc;

        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) errHandler(err);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Way too similar to Brian's answer, but look at the comment I wrote, if you can tackle that, it's gonna be awesome.

Comment: similar yes, his however will still require you to do a second query to get the latest activity. mine would only require you to pull the user since the latest activity would be on the user

Comment: that makes more sense, I updated my answer. is that what you meant?

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the best way to handle it would be to add a post save hook to your `Activity` schema to store the most recent `_id` in the `latest_activity` path of your `User` schema. That way you'd always have access to the id without having to do the extra query.

```
ActivitySchema.post('save', function(doc) {
    UserSchema.findOne({username: doc.owner}).exec(function(err, user){
        if (err)
            console.log(err); //do something with the error
        else if (user) {
            user.latest_activity = doc._id;

            user.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err); //do something with the error
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: wouldn't you still have to do an extra query, whether searching for the activity by `_id` or `user._id`?

Comment: In your original example you were simply assigning the _id value to latest_activity, which achieved the same result. With my method you'd still have to to load the activity detail, if needed, as you would with your example, but it removes the need for an expensive sort query to find the most recent _id every time.

Comment: To sum up your answer : you suggest to lay out data, to add latest activity in the user Schema, which will update the latest activity according to the 'Save' hook? This is nice, but, what if the latest activity is a bit more complicated? for example latest_activity = owner or participated in an activity? (This is not mentioned in the question, I just want to understand better). fill the gap and you'll be the hero

Comment: @Linial I am a little confused here, Brian Shambien's example does handle any complicated situations. It will give you a reference to the activity the user participated in. His example shortens the query time like he said it removes the sort from the find query. Could you explain what you mean by "a bit more complicated"?

Comment: For example : Latest Activity = `db.activity.find({$or:[{owner:username},{participated:{$in:[username]}]}).sort({date:-1}).limit(1)` This means that latest activity is combination of activities by either owned or participated and being sorted from latest to newest.

Comment: Just add another section to the Activity save function where you'd update the `latest_activity` for each User in `participated`.